# geodesic distance

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $G(V,E)$ be a graph , suppose that $\vert N_{i,r} \vert $ be number of vertices whose *geodesic distance* from vertex $i$ is exactly $r$ edges.if $d_i$ the degree of  vertex $i$ and $d_{max} := \max_n {d_n}$, how can resulted that

$$\vert N_{i,r} \vert \leq d_i (d_{\max} -1)^{r-1} ?$$

Comment: What is $d_{max}$? Also, can you give some context? I take it (from the tags) that this is a question about graphs, and I'm guessing that it's about graphs where every node has finite degree, but are there any other hypotheses we should know about, like that the graph is planar, etc.?

Comment: @JohnHughes yes,Edited. $d_{max} := \max_{n} {{d_n}}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

The short answer is that this follows by induction on $r$; it's clearly correct for $r = 1$, because the number of vertices whose distance from $i$ is no more than $1$ is certainly bounded by the degree, $d_i$, of vertex $i$. (And if you only allow one edge between any two vertices, then it's not only bounded but *equal* to $d_i$).

Now you just need to work out the inductive step. When you do so, you can show your progress by clicking on the "edit" link below your question. And if you get stuck, we can help you from there.

Comment: Many thanks for your adequate and clear explanation. I understood  the answer.